# how to import excel sheet (.xlxs) to sql server 2012 db through asp.net and vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2012

It is my first time that am posting a question here.

I have research a lot on the web on how to upload excel sheet (.xlxs) to sql server 2012 database through asp.net and vb.net, however, unfortunately all those research was of no use.

can someone please help me with the source code.

thanks.

Comment: Does your question boil down to: "I want to upload a file to a database, via a web site" ?

Comment: This might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064948/importing-excel-file-to-sql-with-c-sharp-entity-framework/43065951?noredirect=1#comment73226327_43065951 You'll need to translate from c# to vb, but that's not hard.

Comment: I supsect you searched for an exact answer using the wrong keywords. There are dozens of similar samples. It's far easier to search for code that *reads* an Excel file and code that *writes* data to a database. There are thousands of samples. In both cases you should use ADO.NET. You can read Excel files using an OLEDB Provider. You can write data in bulk to SQL Server with SqlBulkCopy

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128419/excel-file-upload-in-asp-net-using-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8290/importing-data-from-existing-file/26603/import-data-from-excel-file#t=201703311306305969285

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel File upload in asp.net using SqlBulkCopy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128419/excel-file-upload-in-asp-net-using-sqlbulkcopy)

Answer (score 0):

SqlBulkCopy class as the name suggests does bulk insert from one source to another and hence all rows from the Excel sheet can be easily read and inserted using the SqlBulkCopy class.

```
<add name = "constr" connectionString = "Data 
 Source=.\SQL2008R2;Database=dbname;User Id=abc;password=xxxxx"/>
```

I have specified the connection strings for the Excel files of both 2003 and 2007 or higher formats in the Web.Config file.

```
<add name = "Excel03ConString" connectionString = 
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 
 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
 <add name = "Excel07+ConString" connectionString = 
 "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended 
  Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES'"/>
```

The HTML Markup consists of ASP.Net FileUpload control and a Button to trigger the file upload process.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
<asp:Button Text="Upload" OnClick = "Upload" runat="server" />
```

You will need to import the following namespaces.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //Upload and save the file
  string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + 
  Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
  FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

string conString = string.Empty;
string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
switch (extension)
{
    case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;
    case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
        conString = 


ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
        break;

}
conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
{
    excel_con.Open();
    string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, 
    null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
    DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

    //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered 
    as String by default.
    dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", 
    typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + 
   sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
    {
        oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
    }
    excel_con.Close();

    string consString = 
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

            //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
            sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
            con.Open();
            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
 }
```

Source is 
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Using-SqlBulkCopy-to-import-Excel-SpreadSheet-data-into-SQL-Server-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx
for further help visit this 
Hope it  will helpful for you